# When I try to access the [:href] attribute of a Nokogiri object, it returns nil - when it's not

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is the Nokogiri object I am dealing with:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x81020c70 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x8101f3fc " May 12 - ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8101f3ac name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8101f258 name="href" value="http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/3011653835.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x8101ee20 "Wordpress Designer">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x8101ecb8 " - ">]>
```

That is stored in an array, so when I do this:

```
my_array.first[:href]
```

It returns nil.

When I do

```
my_array.first.text
```

It returns:

> May 12 - Wordpress Designer -

Which is right...how do I get the href from this particular record?

Comment: we cannot debug a nokogiri element, post the original XML. Anyway, it seems you are getting the href of a p? hard to say, because we don't know exactly what my_array stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object you posted is indeed te first element in `my_array` then `my_array.first` will return a `p` element, not an `a`. It looks like the `a` element you want is the second child of this object, so to access it you actually want:

```
my_array.first.children[1][:href]
```

You could also just access this directly with a CSS or Xpath expression.

Of course I'm really just guessing because you didn't post any of your actual code.

Comment: Perfect....this is almost exactly what I need. `.href` doesn't work, but when I tried `[:href]`, that did. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know that [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D) supports symbols in addition to strings. (The source does show that it calls `to_s` on whatever you pass, so that's nice.)

Comment: Nokogiri also has the colorfully-named "Slop" decorator that makes attributes available as methods, e.g. `link_node.href`. [Docs here](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-slop-21).